# unit testing package naming convention

Tags: unit-testing, naming-conventions

Is there even a **standard** convention for this? I see a lot of different and perhaps misguided package naming that is very mixed in some projects and thus is never consistent:

Let's say I want to write unit tests for something that falls under the 'stuff' package.

```
 com.company.product.amodule.submodule.stuff
```

The unit test could be one of these possibilities (or even somewhere between):

- com.company.**test**.product.amodule.submodule.stuff
- com.company.product.amodule.submodule.stuff.**test**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I put my JUnit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811827/where-should-i-put-my-junit-tests)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have it inside the same namespace (package). I like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) convention to separate source folders

src root-folders:

- production code: src/main/...
- test code: src/test/...

You can map this to your own build-system

Comment: Is there an easy way to follow this convention in Eclipse without using maven?

Answer (score 7):

I tend to keep the tests in the same namespace/package as the code it's testing, but in a different project.

Comment: This is helpful partly because it allows the tests to access package-protected code.